# Reindex pandas DataFrame to match index with another DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, interpolation, reindex

I have two `pandas` `DataFrame`s with different (float) indices.

I want to update the second dataframe to match the first dataframe's index, updating its values to be interpolated using the index.

This is the code I have:

```
from pandas import DataFrame


df1 = DataFrame([
    {'time': 0.2, 'v': 1},
    {'time': 0.4, 'v': 2},
    {'time': 0.6, 'v': 3},
    {'time': 0.8, 'v': 4},
    {'time': 1.0, 'v': 5},
    {'time': 1.2, 'v': 6},
    {'time': 1.4, 'v': 7},
    {'time': 1.6, 'v': 8},
    {'time': 1.8, 'v': 9},
    {'time': 2.0, 'v': 10}
]).set_index('time')

df2 = DataFrame([
    {'time': 0.25, 'v': 1},
    {'time': 0.5, 'v': 2},
    {'time': 0.75, 'v': 3},
    {'time': 1.0, 'v': 4},
    {'time': 1.25, 'v': 5},
    {'time': 1.5, 'v': 6},
    {'time': 1.75, 'v': 7},
    {'time': 2.0, 'v': 8},
    {'time': 2.25, 'v': 9}
]).set_index('time')

df2 = df2.reindex(df1.index.union(df2.index)).interpolate(method='index').reindex(df1.index)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
        v
time     
0.2   NaN
0.4   1.6
0.6   2.4
0.8   3.2
1.0   4.0
1.2   4.8
1.4   5.6
1.6   6.4
1.8   7.2
2.0   8.0
```

That's correct and as I need - however it seems a more complicated statement than it needs to be.

If there a more concise way to do the same, requiring fewer intermediate steps?

Also, is there a way to both interpolate and extrapolate? For example, in the example data above, the linearly extrapolated value for index `0.2` could be `0.8` instead of `NaN`. I know I could `curve_fit`, but again I feel that's more complicated that it may need to be?

Comment: Do you need processing only one column `v`?

Answer (score 0):

One idea with [`numpy.interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), if values in both indices are increased and processing only one column `v`:

```
df1['v1'] = np.interp(df1.index, df2.index, df2['v'])
print(df1)
       v   v1
time         
0.2    1  1.0
0.4    2  1.6
0.6    3  2.4
0.8    4  3.2
1.0    5  4.0
1.2    6  4.8
1.4    7  5.6
1.6    8  6.4
1.8    9  7.2
2.0   10  8.0
```